# Python decorator that resolves some expressions in a function

Tags: python, metaprogramming, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to write a decorator that "pre-resolves" some expressions in a function. That is,

```
CONSTS = {'pos': 1}

@resolve(CONSTS)
def f(x: list):
    return x[CONSTS['pos']]
```

should be the same as if I had written

```
def f(x: list):
    return x[1]
```

The only use will be to substitute string expressions from a single dict with numerical values.

Is it possible to do this, perhaps using `ast`?

(Reason: the transformed function is being passed to another decorator that performs further `ast` magic, and does not support the usage of `dict`.)

Comment: The decorator cannot really change the *inside* of the function it decorates. It can only wrap a call to `f` inside another function, add attributes to `f`, etc.

Comment: It's definitely possible to do this by creating a new code object with different `co_code` and `names`, although this is probably not the nicest solution

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Could you give us some background?

Comment: @md2perpe The example I gave was a sort of MRE. The real code implements a complicated probabilistic algorithm. To improve readability, and work around the limitations of Python type identifiers, the code makes liberal use of dicts that represent mathematical quantities. For example, the probability $\mathbb{P}(X>i)$ is written in the code as `p['X>i']`, which contains a Numpy vector. 

Now I need to make the code run faster by switching to `numba.cuda`. However, Numba's CUDA implementation only supports a limited subset of Python. No dicts.

Comment: I am not sure if the answer solves your question. I am not sure from your last comment if the equation initially returns a list or a dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a fun exercise in metaprogramming.

Because this uses AST rewriting, you need access to the source code of any file you use `@resolve` in.

This also requires you to call resolve with a variable name for the constant dictionary, although it can probably support more complex expressions with very little changes.

If you decide to change the name of `resolve` (for example to `resolve_constants` or something, don't forget to also change `ast.Name('resolve')` in `visit_FunctionDef`.

It should theoretically work in combination with other decorators, however I haven't tested that at all.

```
import ast
from functools import partial
import inspect
import sys

CONSTS = {'pos': 1}

class Resolver(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def __init__(self, consts):
        self.consts = consts

    def visit_Subscript(self, node):
        match node:
            case ast.Subscript(ast.Name(self.consts_name), ast.Constant(value)):
                return ast.Constant(self.consts[value])
        return super().generic_visit(node)

    def visit_FunctionDef(self, node):
        # prevent infinite invocation of resolve
        # and also record the name of the constants dictionary
        for deco in node.decorator_list:
            match deco:
                case ast.Call(ast.Name('resolve'), [ast.Name(consts_name)]):
                    self.consts_name = consts_name
                    break
        node.decorator_list = []
        return super().generic_visit(node)

def resolve(f, *, dictionary=None):
    if dictionary is None:
        return partial(resolve, dictionary=f)

    # Get the AST from source code
    source = inspect.getsource(f)
    tree = ast.parse(source)

    # Transform the AST
    new_tree = ast.fix_missing_locations(Resolver(dictionary).visit(tree))

    # Execute the AST as part of the original namespace, so it can still access other globals
    ns = sys.modules[f.__module__].__dict__
    exec(compile(new_tree, f.__module__, 'exec'), ns)

    # The desired function is found in the namespace
    return ns[f.__name__]

@resolve(CONSTS)
def f(x: list):
    return x[CONSTS['pos']]

# So you know it's not accessing the dictionary during the function call:
del CONSTS

print(f([1, 2]))
```